# Organising an array of URLs by hierarchy

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, sorting, multidimensional-array

I have built a web scraper that recursively gets all URLs from a specific website and stores them in an array

Example below:

```
$array = [
    'http://site.test',
    'http://site.test/blog',
    'http://site.test/blog/blog1',
    'http://site.test/blog/blog2',
    'http://site.test/services',
    'http://site.test/services/service1',
    'http://site.test/services/service2',
    'http://site.test/services/service2/sub-service',
    'http://site.test/product',
    'http://site.test/product/product1',
    'http://site.test/product/product1',
];
```

I am looking for some sort of way to organise this array into a multidimensional array so that I can see what pages are child pages and of which section something like the below structure

ie:

```
Home
----blog
--------article1
--------article2
----services
--------service1
--------service2
------------sub-service1
-----product
--------product1
--------product2
```

I have tried looping through and extracting certain segments of each string but cannot seem to get the desired result.

Ideally I would like to have the result in an array or even in displayed in a multi-level list for display purposes.

Any guidance would be much appreciated!

Comment: I would first remove the root domain (http://site.test/) from each URL, then explode() the remainder on the "/" separator.  Then loop through the results, building your multidimensional array as you go.

Comment: Sort based on explode length. This way, parents always come before child now. Next, is to extract parents and assign version numbers to each value like `1`,`1.1`,`1.1.2` etc. Now, sort based on these version numbers and you are done. Will try tomorrow and let you know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Algorithm:**

- Remove the prefix `http://` for now as it is useless for our requirement. You can add it later on again.
- Next is to sort all the elements using `usort`. Here, based on length obtained from exploding based on `/`.
- Now, we can be assured that *all parents are before child* in the array.
- Next is to assign version number/rank to each link. Naming is as follows:

  `'http://site.test'` => 1

  `'http://site.test/blog'` => 1.1

  `'http://site.test/services'` => 1.2

  `'http://site.test/blog/blog1'` => 1.1.1
- Above is the strategy in which version numbers will be assigned.
- Now, we just need to sort the array based on this version numbers using `uasort`
  and you are done.

**Snippet:**

```
<?php

$array = [
    'http://site.test',
    'http://site.test/blog',
    'http://site.test/blog/blog1',
    'http://site.test/blog/blog2',
    'http://site.test/services',
    'http://site.test/services/service1',
    'http://site.test/services/service2',
    'http://site.test/services/service2/sub-service',
    'http://site.test/product',
    'http://site.test/product/product1',
];

// remove http:// 
foreach($array as &$val){
    $val = substr($val,7);
}

// sort based on length on explode done on delimiter '/' 
usort($array, function($a,$b){
    return count(explode("/",$a)) <=> count(explode("/",$b));
});

$ranks = [];
$child_count = [];

// assign ranks/version numbers

foreach($array as $link){
    $parent = getParent($link);
    if(!isset($ranks[$parent])){
        $ranks[$link] = 1;
    }else{
        $child_count[$parent]++;
        $ranks[$link] = $ranks[$parent] . "." . $child_count[$parent];
    }
    $child_count[$link] = 0;
}

function getParent($link){
    $link = explode("/",$link);
    array_pop($link);
    return implode("/",$link);
}

// sort based on version numbers
uasort($ranks,function($a,$b){
    $version1 = explode(".", $a);
    $version2 = explode(".", $b);
    foreach($version1 as $index => $v_num){
        if(!isset($version2[$index])) return 1;
        $aa = intval($v_num);
        $bb = intval($version2[$index]);
        if($aa < $bb) return -1;
        if($bb < $aa) return 1;
    }
    
    return count($version1) <=> count($version2);
});

// get the actual product links that were made as keys 
$array = array_keys($ranks);
print_r($array);// now you can attach back http:// prefix if you like
```

---

**Note:** Current algorithm removes duplicates as well as there is no point in keeping them.

---

**#Update:**

Since you need a multidimensional hierarchical array, we can keep track of parent and child array link references and insert children into their respective parents.

```
<?php

$array = [
'http://site.test',
'http://site.test/blog',
'http://site.test/blog/blog1',
'http://site.test/blog/blog2',
'http://site.test/services',
'http://site.test/services/service1',
'http://site.test/services/service2',
'http://site.test/services/service2/sub-service',
'http://site.test/product',
'http://site.test/product/product1',
];

foreach($array as &$val){
    $val = substr($val,7);
}

usort($array, function($a,$b){
    return count(explode("/",$a)) <=> count(explode("/",$b));
});

$hier = [];
$set = [];

foreach($array as $link){
    $parent = getParent($link);
    if(!isset($set[$parent])){
        $hier[$link] = [];
        $set[$link] = &$hier[$link];
    }else{
        $parent_array = &$set[$parent];
        $parent_array[$link] = [];
        $set[$link] = &$parent_array[$link];
    }    
}

function getParent($link){
    $link = explode("/",$link);
    array_pop($link);
    return implode("/",$link);
}


print_r($hier);
```

Comment: Thanks for this, the logic makes sense to me but doesn't give me the end result I was looking for what I was looking for unfortunately

Comment: @JonnyFoley Can you share an example link to show for which input it doesn't work?

Comment: @JonnyFoley It works fine. See here http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/85ed3aece2d2dbc6fa5a01bd8c3d4a9d41d3cb4d All links are grouped properly

Comment: the code executes perfectly and the ordering is correct however I was hoping to have this as a multidimensional array by the end so I can use it as a sitemap, maybe not exactly like below but something like, $a = [
            ['site.test'] => [
                ['blog'] => ['blog1', 'blog2'],
                ['services'] => [
                    'service1',
                    'service2' => [
                        'sub-service1', 'sub-service2'
                    ]
                ],
                ['product'] => ['product1', 'product2'],
            ]
        ];

Comment: @JonnyFoley Ohh I overlooked that. I will amend shortly.

Comment: thanks for your help, struggling to get my head around this for some reason!

Comment: @JonnyFoley Updated the same now.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/235674/discussion-between-jonnyfoley-and-nice-dev).

Answer (score 2):

Let's try) we have an array of links

```
$array = [
    'http://site.test',
    'http://site.test/blog',
    'http://site.test/blog/blog1',
    'http://site.test/blog/blog2',
    'http://site.test/services',
    'http://site.test/services/service1',
    'http://site.test/services/service2',
    'http://site.test/services/service2/sub-service',
    'http://site.test/product',
    'http://site.test/product/product1',
    'http://site.test/product/product2',
];
```

For creating a tree we should create the Node class

```
class Node
{
    private array $childNodes;

    private string $name;

    public function __construct(string $name)
    {
        $this->name = $name;
        $this->childNodes = [];
    }

    public function getName(): string
    {
        return $this->name;
    }

    public function addChildNode(Node $node): void
    {
        $this->childNodes[$node->getName()] = $node;
    }

    public function hasChildNode(string $name): bool
    {
        return array_key_exists($name, $this->childNodes);
    }

    public function getChildNode(string $name): Node
    {
        return $this->childNodes[$name];
    }

    public function getChildNodes(): array
    {
        return $this->childNodes;
    }
}
```

And Tree class, that used Node class.
Method appendUrl parses URL and builds nodes chain.

```
class Tree
{
    private Node $head;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->head = new Node('Head');
    }

    public function getHead(): Node
    {
        return $this->head;
    }

    public function appendUrl(string $url): void
    {
        $parsedUrl = parse_url($url);
        $uri = sprintf('%s//%s', $parsedUrl['scheme'], $parsedUrl['host']);
        $keys = array_filter(explode('/', $parsedUrl['path'] ?? ''));
        $keys = [$uri, ...$keys];

        $node = $this->head;
        foreach ($keys as $key) {
            if (!$node->hasChildNode($key)) {
                $prevNode = $node;
                $node = new Node($key);
                $prevNode->addChildNode($node);
            } else {
                $node = $node->getChildNode($key);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Now we create ConsoleTreeDrawer class that draw our tree to console

```
class ConsoleTreeDrawer
{
    public function draw(Tree $tree): void
    {
        $node = $tree->getHead();
        $this->drawNode($node);
    }

    private function drawNode(Node $node, int $level = 1): void
    {
        $prefix = implode('', array_fill(0, 2 * $level, '-'));

        print("{$prefix}{$node->getName()}\n");

        foreach ($node->getChildNodes() as $childNode) {
            $this->drawNode($childNode, $level + 1);
        }
    }
}
```

And let`s use our classes

```
$tree = new Tree();

foreach ($array as $url) {
    $tree->appendUrl($url);
}

$drawer = new ConsoleTreeDrawer();
$drawer->draw($tree);
```

And we drew the tree

```
--Head
----http//site.test
------blog
--------blog1
--------blog2
------services
--------service1
--------service2
----------sub-service
------product
--------product1
```